# SQL Server error: 26 - Error locating server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get started with SQL Server 2012, but I keep getting the error

> a network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible... error: 26 - Error locating server/instance specified)

I've read some links that try to resolve the issue, such as by going to SQL Server configuration manager and looking at SQL Server Services. However, if I right-click on it, I don't see "properties". There's also nothing to do the right as it says "There are no items to show in this view". I also do not see "SQL Server Browser anywhere

What else can I do?

Comment: 1. Make sure in configuration manager/protocols that TCP/IP is enabled. 2. make sure you reference the name correctly, i.e. if you've got named instance than address should reflect it (localhost\MSSQL) 3. among /services in manager SQL Server browser should be running

Comment: http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/03/11/resolving-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server/

Comment: I think you have installed SQL client not server. Try to install SQL server again.

Comment: Instead of providing instance name, give a period ".". It points to localhost.

Comment: In that link, I do not see `SQL Server Surface Area Configuration` when I follow the instructions

Comment: where is instance name? you mean 'server name'? When I try that, I now get "provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40"

Comment: When I try to check if TCP/IP is enabled, by the following the link below, there is nothing in the Results pane when I click on `SQL Server Services`..https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909712%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: If I follow the steps in this link, I am unable to click `Protocols for`..https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: `provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40` for this error may be coxz you are giving only instance name . provide your server name also with instance name like **servername\instancename**

Comment: If I try servername/., I get the same error 26 message as before

Comment: **What exactly** did you install? Just the *Management Studio* by chance? Sounds like you really *don't have* SQL Server (the core engine) on your machine..

Answer (score 1):

This should work for all SQL Server versions.

First of all: Go to "Run" and write the command: service.msc

Second: Find SQL Server (User), one click on it and push the start button from the top left corner of the window.

Third: Go back to the SQL Server Management Studio and try to connect. Now it should work. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all ,open command prompt.

and type : `sqlcmd -L`

try to find your server in that list.

after that,open ssms (management studio) and give credentials.

probably try to give localhost,local, '.' settings.